# Cannot login to yammer using yam.connect.logonButton in IE11

Tags: sdk, yammer

Trying to login using yam.connect.loginButton, works fine on firefox and chrome but not on IE (I am using IE11).  The response has an auth but no user object. Or sometimes the popup window doesn't close and the callback is never called.  Code I used is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script id="yammer-js-include" data-app-id="APP-CLIENT-ID-GOES-HERE" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="yammer-login"></span>
<script>
    yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', 
        function (response) {
            console.dir(response);
            document.getElementById('yammer-login').innerHTML = 'user ' + (typeof response.user !== 'undefined' ? 'exists in response' : 'is missing!'); 
        }
    );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention that was the code you used, but did you replace the data-app-id with the one provided from your app on https://yammer.com/client_applications ?

Assuming yes, a lot of people run in to problems with IE and not having Yammer urls added to Trusted Sites in IE.  If you can add more logs from your console output that it would help.

You can read more about what to include in your Trusted Sites here:

http://developer.yammer.com/connect/#IETrustedSites

Comment: I added https://*.yammer.com to trusted sites and this did not resolve.  I also tried setting the Trusted Sites security level to low and this also did not work.

Comment: I put APP-CLIENT-ID-GOES-HERE in the code above because I did not want to share my app id but please be assured that the proper app id is being used in my code.

Answer (score 0):

When I add the host of where my app was running also in the Trusted Sites, it worked.
http://kendomen.wordpress.com/2014/11/06/yammer-authentication-with-javascript-and-yammer-sdk/